# What is the difference between AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy and AddPolicyHandler?

Tags: microservices, asp.net-core-webapi, polly, resiliency, httpclientfactory

I want to apply resiliency strategy using [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly).

I am using `HttpClientFactory` from ASP.NET Core 2.1. I found some guide on [Polly GitHub wiki](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory). There are two ways of such policy configuration - using `AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy` and `AddPolicyHandler`, but not much of an explanation.

What are the differences between them?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`.AddTransientHttpErrorPolicy(...)` embeds a specification for you of the *what* to handle (network failures, 5xx and 408 responses as described [in the wiki](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory#using-addtransienthttperrorpolicy)). You only have to specify the *how* to handle (eg retry, circuit-breaker).

With `.AddPolicyHandler(...)`, you specify the whole policy yourself: both *what* to handle (.`Handle<>()`, `.Or<>()`, `.OrResult<HttpResponseMessage()` etc) and *how* to handle (eg retry, circuit-breaker).  As shown [here in the Polly wiki](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory#using-any-policy-configured-via-the-traditional-polly-syntax).

Beyond that, there are no differences in how `IHttpClientFactory` works with the configured policies.